# How to build a jsTree in Jade dynamically?

Tags: javascript, pug, jstree

I am using jquery, jstree, jade, and nodejs.
My aim is to generate a tree dynamically, but it fails.

The inline javascript code is working fine but there is no tree output.
When I inspect the html it is clear that jade closes the first ul tag before it opens the li tag.

Here is the jade code:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css')
    script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js')  
    script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js')  
    script.
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#selTree').jstree(ghcomp);
        });
body
  #selTree
    ul
    -for(let r=1; r<ghcomp.length; r++) {
    -for(let gh in ghcomp[r]) {
      li #{gh}
        ul
        -for(let c=0; c<ghcomp[r][gh].length; c++) {
          li #{ghcomp[r][gh][c].comp}
        -}
    -}
    -}
```

And here is what jade produces as output:

```
<div id="selTree"><ul></ul><li>I<ul></ul><li>B</li></li><li>L<ul></ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></li><li>M<ul></ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>e</li></li><li>Production<ul></ul><li>virtual</li></li><li>Tech<ul></ul><li>na</li></li><li>Themato<ul></ul><li>C1</li><li>C2</li><li>C3</li><li>C4</li><li>C5</li><li>C6</li><li>C7</li><li>C8</li></li></div>
```

How can I gain control over the production process here?

E.g.: I could generate HTML on the fly easily. Could I hand that over to jade?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite this in native Jade [iteration](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration) and it will build the DOM properly for you, not to mention being a lot easier to both read and debug.  I'd also recommend using more descriptive variable names in complex nested iterations like this.

```
ul
  each gh, ghIndex in ghcomp
    li= gh
      ul
        each c in gh
          li= c
```

It would be easier to understand exactly what you want to do here if you posted the JSON that is feeding the Jade template, but here are the problems I see:

The reason that Jade is closing the ul tags before embedding the `li` inside it is that you haven't indented the next line, therefore it will be a sibling to the ul instead of a child:

```
ul
-for(let r=1; r<ghcomp.length; r++) {
```

and

```
ul
-for(let c=0; c<ghcomp[r][gh].length; c++) {
```

These should be changed to (if you stick with this method):

```
ul
  -for(let r=1; r<ghcomp.length; r++) {
```

and

```
ul
  -for(let c=0; c<ghcomp[r][gh].length; c++) {
```